# Is 'senior' a count usage here?

Tags: grammar

Consider this sentence: " they are both one year my seniors" should I just use 'senior' instead of 'seniors'? or should I use the plural form given the fact that I am talking about two people?

Comment: 'senior' is being used as an adjective here. So there's no concept of count or mass to be applied (in this context).

Answer (score 1):

"They are both one year my senior" would be the most proper. The plural form doesn't really apply here! The plural form would only be used in cases where you they "they are both seniors", or something of the sort. The word senior, in the case of the example, can not be pluralized.

Comment: I agree with this: 'be someone's senior/junior' is a fixed expression. But Google results don't show this. You could perhaps cite Google Ngram results. /  "They are both one year older than me" is what most Anglophones would use.